# response.sendFile not working in http server

Tags: node.js, express

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080
var Controllers = require('./app/Controllers');
Controllers.uploadFile(app);


app.get('/', function(request, response){
    console.log("here");
    response.sendFile('/home/vk/index.html');
});

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    console.log("Rosie is live now2.");
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end();
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Rosie is live now.");
});
```

Here's my code. I want to execute the response.sendFile in the GET route. But looks like it is not working as I don't see "here" in console. One thing I can do is put all my routes logic inside requestListner function, but it will mess up my code.

Every time I visit the code, I see "Rosie is live now2." in console.

I've noticed in HTTPS nodejs server, there's no such problem. You can separately write routes.

Is it because 8080 is a default port?

Isn't it possible to write routes separately in HTTP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two types of creating a server and consequently, your express routes are not part of your functioning server at all.  Change your code to this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
    
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    console.log("here");
    response.sendFile('/home/vk/index.html');
});

const server = app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Rosie is live now.");
});
```

to get a basic Express erver up and running that responds to your one route.  Then, if you want to add some more things to it via your controllers file, that can also be done, but you'd have to show us what's in that file and describe what you're trying to accomplish with that.

Or, if you want to manually create the server instance yourself, you can do this:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
    
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    console.log("here");
    response.sendFile('/home/vk/index.html');
});

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Rosie is live now.");
});
```

The point with both of these is that `app` needs to be your main request handler for the server so that it gets called on each incoming request and can then match the routes that you define with `app.get(...)` and `app.post(...)`, etc....

In your existing code, `app` was never hooked to your server at all.  In the first body of code, here `app.listen()` both creates the server instance and associates `app` with it.  In the second body of code here, you do that manually with your own code.

Comment: I see the trick you did in 2nd solution. you just passed app in the createServer. I was passing a function that's why it wasn't working. Both are optional things? I mean either you can use app or a customer function with req, res params?

Comment: That's why it was working fine in my HTTPS server. I didn't pay attention to this thing.

Comment: @Vikas - Well, `app` is a function that expects `(req, res, next)` to be passed to it and when it's called, it runs the Express routing for the incoming request.  There are multiple ways to get it registered as the main listener on your server.  My two code blocks are two of the ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

try changing this block:

```
const requestListener = function (req, res, next) { //<added this next
    console.log("Rosie is live now2.");
  // res.writeHead(200); //< -- remove this line
  // res.end(); //<-remove this line too
  next();
}
```

I am not sure if this is could solve the problem, but you could try this and see if that works

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Express as your web application framework, then you don't need to use `http` module for creating server inside of your code!

try to changing this block:

```
...
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Rosie is live now.");
});
```

Comment: still it will create HTTP server? I need only HTTP.

Comment: You're creating server with `http` module, but you're expecting your server to work with Express response methods like `response.sendFile()`!